# Gunicorn and Nginx: 504 Gateway Time-Out

Tags: python, nginx, flask, wsgi, gunicorn

I'm running a Flask application using gunicorn and nginx on an Ubuntu server however I'm receiving a 504 Gateway Time-Out error when I load the page. This is how I've set the application up following [this](https://exploreflask.com/deployment.html):

I have a file named `app` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` with the following contents:

```
# Redirect www.psflask.net to psflask.net
server {
        server_name www.psflask.net;
        rewrite ^ http://psflask.net/ permanent;
}

# Handle requests to psflask.net on port 80
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name psflask.net;

                # Handle all locations
        location / {
                        # Pass the request to Gunicorn
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

                # Set some HTTP headers so that our app knows where the
                # request really came from
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

I created a symlink using:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/psflask.net /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/psflask.net
```

and then I restart nginx with `sudo service nginx restart`

I run gunicorn with:

```
gunicorn run:app -p psflask.pid -D
```

I try to access the page however, it takes a while to load and then I get a 504 Gateway Time-Out error. What is the issue? Thanks.

Edit:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 125
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.6
< Date: Sat, 19 Sep 2015 14:43:37 GMT
< 
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Home - microblog</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Hello, welcome to my site.</h1>
 </body>
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: if you ping psflask.net do you get your ip? (have you registered the domain with some name servers?)

Comment: Yeah the domain name does point to the server. Otherwise the nginx error would not even show.

Comment: what do you get if you request your app directly via `8000` port? if you run your app on your local computer, you may just navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in your browser. if you run it on remote server, you may run in command line: `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000`. if you get the same result, the problem is with your app, rather than Nginx

Comment: The application works fine locally, for some reason when I run the app, gunicorn uses port `5000` and port `8000`. If I set nginx to listen to `5000` instead, the `504` error disappears and instead I get a `502 bad gateway error`?

Comment: @PavSidhu so what is the result of running `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000` ?

Comment: @Curious I posted the result in the question.

Comment: @PavSidhu is result the same when you request `http://psflask.net:8000`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90109/discussion-between-pav-sidhu-and-curious).